# Closure Proof - General Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space, $A \subseteq X$, and $U \in \tau(X)$. Prove that $cl(U \cap A) = cl(U \cap clA)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$A \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)$ so $U \cap A \subseteq U \cap\operatorname{cl}(A)$ and so $$\operatorname{cl}(U \cap A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl} (U \cap \operatorname{cl}(A))$$

For the reverse, pick $x \in \operatorname{cl}(U \cap \operatorname{cl}(A))$.

Let $O$ be open, with $x \in O$. We know $O \cap (U \cap \operatorname{cl}(A)) \neq \emptyset$, as $x$ lies in the closure of that set.

So $O \cap U$ is open (here we use that $U$ is open) and intersects $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ hence $O \cap U$ intersects $A$ too. Otherwise put: $O$ intersects $U \cap A$, and as $O$ was arbitrary, $x \in \operatorname{cl}(U \cap A)$ as required for the reverse inclusion.

Comment: How do we know that $U \subseteq cl(A)$?

Comment: @LuisPerez It's a typo; it should be $A\subseteq \text{cl}(A)$.

Comment: @LAP13 typo, now edited.